# How to get the first element found "further in the DOM" after a specific element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm trying to use jQuery to select the first header on the page. After I found that element, I want the first image tag that is found after that element.

There are a lot of useful functions to traverse them DOM. However, it looks like they can only find elements that are either "in the same parent tag" or "siblings of" the header.

I prepared this example but the html could be something completely different:

```
<img id="img-one" src="random.png" />
<div>
  <h1>Here is the title</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <img id="img-two" src="random.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>
    <img id="img-three" src="random.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

I find the title here with `$("h1").first()`, now I need the first img tag occurring after that title, which is "img-two" in this example.

Also: The nesting of the random divs I put in place can be completely different so I can't use something like `.parent().next("div"). ...`, it has to be more generic.

My first idea is that there might be a function that gives you the index of an element globally over the entire DOM. In that case I could get the index of the h1 and the indexes of all the img tags and then compare which one of the image-indexes is larger and closest to the index of the h1.

Is there such a function or are there other selectors I might have missed?

Here is a codepen setup to play with: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPOjmQ

Comment: why not just use `$("#img-two")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This handles your example:

```
function getFirstImgAfterH1(h1) {
  var $allH1Img = $("h1, img");
  var h1Index = $allH1Img.index(h1);
  for (var i = h1Index + 1; i < $allH1Img.length; i++) {
    if ($allH1Img[i].tagName === "IMG") {
      return $allH1Img[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
getFirstImgAfterH1($("h1").first());
```

You should observe that it can be generalized for `selector` and `$element` using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) like this:

```
function getFirstAfter(selector, $element) {
  var selectors = selector + ", " + $element[0].tagName;
  var $allSelectorElement = $(selectors);
  var elementIndex = $allSelectorElement.index($element);
  for (var i = elementIndex + 1; i < $allSelectorElement.length; i++) {
    if ($($allSelectorElement[i]).is(selector)) {
      return $allSelectorElement[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
getFirstAfter("img", $("h1").first());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I knew something with indexes would do the trick but was too focused on getting the index "dom-wide". Selecting both h1 and img and determining the index in that array is very clever.

Answer (score 1):

A way of doing this can be to grab your header, then grab every image tag. 
Iterate over the image tags to find the closest 'absolute top' position from your headers absolute position.

Probably not the best way, but it should work.